# How to allow uppercase letters,lowercase letters and spaces in ajaxtoolkit filtered textbox extender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

In ajaxtoolkit filtered textbox extender it is not allowing spaces in between characters

Please give me solution what to put in filterType and validchars

Code

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server"    
FilterType="LowercaseLetters, UppercaseLetters" ValidChars=" " 
     TargetControlID="txtFirstName" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender 
    ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" 
    runat="server"    
    FilterType="LowercaseLetters, UppercaseLetters,Custom" 
    ValidChars=" " 
    TargetControlID="txtFirstName" />
```

Put "Custom" in Filter Type ,then its working fine